# Чёрные полосы вместо ресурсов (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

```
public class CoreTG extends Game {

public Preferences preferences;
public Skin skin;
public Json reader;
public BitmapFont menuFont, speechFont;
private static final String FONT_CHARACTERS =
        "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.;,{}\"´`'<>~";

@Override
public void create () {
        reader = new Json();
        preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("tech");
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/ds_pixel_cyr.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter param = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        param.size = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 21;
        param.characters = FONT_CHARACTERS;
        param.color = Color.BLACK;
        menuFont = generator.generateFont(param);
        param.size =  (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 10) / 27;
        speechFont = generator.generateFont(param);
        generator.dispose();
        skin = new Skin();
        TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/pack.atlas"));
        skin.addRegions(atlas);
        atlas.dispose();
        this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
    }
}
```

Все ресурсы, которые я получаю из этого Skin через метод getDrawable, отображаются как чёрные прямоугольники. Когда я беру незапакованный ресурс, он отображается прекрасно. В другом вопросе я прочитал, что это может быть из-за где-то применённого к нему метода dispose(), но я сам его к skin`у нигде не применяю. Значит, либо он где-то вызывается автоматически, либо проблема в другом. Вы можете мне помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался. Проблема возникала из-за того, что я применял dispose() к atlas`y. При добавлении этой строки в метод dispose() в классе CoreTG всё решилось.